# google sheets scripting & google forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am having some trouble with a google sheets script and a form.

I created a script that inserts data into multiple workbooks based on the inputs from a form. I worked in a test environment using copies of the sheets I wanted to update while I was debugging and developing.

Everything worked perfectly.

When I tried migrating the script to the live sheets, I created a new form from the live spreadsheet using the Tools/Create Form menu.

When I tried running the script, I ran into an error message when the code hits the line:

```
var form = FormApp.openByUrl(formURL);
```

"No item with the given ID could be found, or you do not have permission to access it."

While trying to debug the issue, it seems to come down to the form URL having a "e/" following the "/d/"

form URL for my Dev test:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/  /viewform

form URL for my Live test:
https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/  /viewform

I've tried recreating the form multiple times in both my live and test environments, and the form urls now always have the /d/e/ syntax in them.

All the examples I have seem about linking scripts to forms always show the urls without the "e/".

Does anyone know why my form URLs are always popping up with that syntax and how I can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong Google Form URL. Instead of the respondent view URL (the URL having `/viewform`) use the editor view URL (the one having `/edit`)